# how to solve ubuntu permissions error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ubuntu, gulp, bower

When I try to run bower install I get this error:

```
  bower EACCES        
EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/user/.cache/bower/packages/060f2023684d502403f2380d2be22dba-0.14.3.lock'

Console trace:
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:81:37)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:110:26)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Logger.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:48:20
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:844:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:788:41)
System info:
Bower version: 1.7.9
Node version: 4.4.7
```

and when I try to run gulp serve I get

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/filepath.css'
    at Error (native)
```

I think these are permission errors so I have tried running

```
 sudo chown -R user:user /home/user/.config/configstore
```

also running `sudo  chmod -R 777 *` in the directory

I my system is ubuntu. I am not sure how can I solve this problem

when I checked my .config folder I get this

```
.config  ls -l configstore
total 64
-rw------- 1 root root   2 Aug  4 18:29 bower-github.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user  3 May 12 17:29 bower-github.yml
-rw------- 1 use ruser 47 Mar 18 13:50 insight-bower.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 use ruser 36 Sep 28  2015 insight-bower.yml
-rw------- 1 use ruser 47 Feb 29 18:08 insight-generator-gulp-angular.json
-rw------- 1 use ruser 47 Aug  4 11:16 insight-yo.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 use ruser 37 Jan 20  2016 insight-yo.yml
-rw------- 1 root root  55 Aug  4 18:29 update-notifier-bower.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user114 Jan 20  2016 update-notifier-bower.yml
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 45 Aug 27  2015 update-notifier-generator-generator.yml
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user130 Aug 27  2015 update-notifier-generator-gulp-webapp.yml
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user124 Aug 27  2015 update-notifier-generator-mocha.yml
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user125 Aug 27  2015 update-notifier-generator-webapp.yml
-rw------- 1 user user 55 Aug  4 11:16 update-notifier-yo.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user111 Jan 20  2016 update-notifier-yo.yml
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 60 Aug 27  2015 yo.yml
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? What is your .config folder perms?

Comment: @SteveLacy added some more detail above. My question is just that how can I solve this issue